# React native - Adapt horizontal ScrollView's height to its children

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

See the following [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/CcvBB8jlsY)

I need to adapt the height of the ScrollView to its children. It seems that ScrollView is using `{ flex: 1 }` by default (not sure). Any ideas how to make it possible?

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <ScrollView horizontal style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
    <View
      style={{ width: 60, height: 30, marginLeft: 5, backgroundColor: 'lime' }}
    />
  </ScrollView>

  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }} />
</View>
```

Thank you.

Note: Is it possible to do it without using `{ height: 30 }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the ScrollView inside a View does the trick.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View>
     <ScrollView horizontal style={{ backgroundColor:"red" }}>
        <View style={{ width: 60, height: 30, marginLeft: 5, backgroundColor: "lime" }} />
     </ScrollView>
  </View>

   <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:"yellow" }} />
</View>
```